# how to set content on Jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$("#note_content").dialog({
            title: "Note",
            modal: true,
            width:'auto',
            height:'auto',
            resizable:false,

            open: function(){
                var note_text = $('#note_content').attr('note_text');
     }
}
```

In my code I am trying set note_text as content of dialog, any idea how could I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a content place holder inside your dialog, for example:

```
<div id="noteContent" title="Basic dialog">
   <p id="contentholder"> This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>

$("#note_content").dialog({
    title: "Note",
    modal: true,
    width:'auto',
    height:'auto',
    resizable:false,

    open: function(){
        var note_text = $('#note_content').attr('note_text');
       $("#contentholder").val(note_text)
    }
}
```

You had your note_text assigned to a variable in this line:

```
var note_text = $('#note_content').attr('note_text');
```

However, you didn't assign the note_text variable to the placeholder.

Comment: Your solution is correct. however .val() doesn't work on <p> tags. you need to use .text() function to overwrite the content.

Answer (score 19):

You can try this: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ldktu/160/)

```
var SplitText = "Title"
var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
    .html(SplitText )
    .dialog({
        height: 500,
        width: 600,
        title: 'Title'});

$dialog.dialog('open');

$dialog.html('Some text');
​
```

​

​